# How to check if a Credential exists in a SQL Server instance?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

How can you check if a Credential already exists in a SQL Server instance, so as to avoid an error when running a `DROP CREDENTIAL` ?

Normally I use the `SCRIPT AS ...` and `DROP And CREATE To` feature in SSMS to create the script, but the `CREDENTIAL` doesn't have that option

Answer (score 12, accepted):

```
if exists (select * from sys.credentials where name = 'CredName')
    drop credential CredName
```

Comment: Thank you ... any idea why the DROP / CREATE option isn't on the SSMS menu like with the rest of the database artefacts?

Comment: It's not present in SSMS 2012 either, and the `Properties -> Script Action As` button doesn't work.  No idea why.

Comment: The existence or not of a feature in SSMS is typically bijective of whether or not the feature exists in SMO. However, in this case, it seems not to be the case. Specifically, a Drop() method exists on the Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.Credential class. I just tested it with a dummy credential and it works. I've logged a Connect option here: https://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedback/details/747691/drop-credential-not-available-through-ssms.